# Redirect One Domain To https 2nd Domain http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have a domain where every page is set to https in .htaccess.
There is also a 2nd domain for the Irish version of the site, where we don't have a certificate, so we need the pages to be set to http.
We also want to ensure both domains are set to www.
To further complicate the matter, users can login to part of the site, and we want those pages to be secure. What we plan is to detect the Irish domain and login page and redirect to the main domain.

I can code individual parts of this in .htaccess, but I am not sure how to code the whole scenario without it getting horribly complicated, messy and difficult to debug. I also don't want to double redirect pages unnecessarily.

So in summary:

```
(www.)example.com -> https://www.example.com
(www.)example.ie -> http://www.example.ie
(www.)example.ie/login.php -> https://www.example.com/login.php
```

I would be grateful for any help, haven't been able to find any similar scenarios.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways of doing this. Assuming you're differentiating based on the host header (vs, say, using unique IP-based virtual hosts), you could do something like:

```
# Special case for Irish login page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.ie$
RewriteRule ^/login\.php$ https://www.example.com/login.php [R]

# By default use HTTPS
RewriteRule .* - [E=CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME:https]
# For (www.)example.ie use HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.ie$
RewriteRule .* - [E=CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME:http]

# Ensure www prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.(com|ie)$
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ %{ENV:CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.example.%1/$1 [R]

# Ensure correct request scheme
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{ENV:CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME} =https
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R]
```

Comment: That looks about perfect, thanks very much Avi. I will test this now, but it's definitely less complicated (and clearer) than the way I was trying to code it.

Comment: Ah drat! Everything looks fine, but we are using Apache 2.2.29 so I can't use REQUEST_SCHEME. Running through a validator it seems to be failing on: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} -ne %{ENV:CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME}.

Comment: Seems you're right, looking at the mod_rewrite source for 2.2.29 (https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/), there is no REQUEST_SCHEME variable. I'll update to account for that.

Comment: Thanks Avi.  I tried an update to set an env variable for http/https and to compare that, but it didn't work properly. No more 500 errors, but it didn't set https or www consistently. Must be very close. I am learning more just from seeing how you coded it though.

Comment: Closer, at least it's not giving 500 errors now.  However, on both .com and .ie sites it's not forcing the www, and still trying to force https for the .ie site, as well as allowing http for the .com site. I'm sure it's got to be something really simple, will post my code in a few mins, also reset history on Firefox and make sure it's not caching anything (despite forcing reloads of pages you can never be 100% sure it's not caching something).

Answer (score 0):

Edited code to reflect Avi's solution. For some reason it's still not forcing www, and it's not forcing https for the .com site. Unfortunately running under Apache 2.2.29 on our production web server we can't use "REQUEST_SCHEME":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

## ERROR DOCUMENT PROCESSING ##
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
## ERROR DOCUMENT PROCESSING ##

## TRAP REQUESTS FOR IMAGE DOES NOT EXIST ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule .* /products/sq/250sq/no_image_available.jpg [R]

## FORCE URL CHANGES FOR DOMAINS ##

# Special case for Irish login page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.ie$
RewriteRule ^/login\.php$ https://www.example.com/login.php [R]

# By default use HTTPS
RewriteRule .* - [E=CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME:https]
# For (www.)example.ie use HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.ie$
RewriteRule .* - [E=CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME:http]

# Ensure www prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.(com|ie)$
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ %{ENV:CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.example.%1/$1 [R]

# Ensure correct request scheme
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{ENV:CORRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME} =https
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R]
```